# Fixed-width viewport in Windows Phone

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, meta

I'm trying to have a fixed width viewport in Windows Phone. It works well in iOS but for some reason it won't work in Windows Phone, although I tried different solutions (`meta name=MobileOptimized`, `@-ms-viewport`, etc.).

You can find my sample page at http://oran.ge/PzWxHX.

Here's the reference rendering in iOS: http://grab.by/v8IM

CSS:

```
.bouton {
    display: block;
    width:75%;
    margin:auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background:#f60;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 14px sans-serif;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 {
    font:bold 14px sans-serif;
    margin: 15px auto;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

}
.snippet {
    width:208px;
    height:326px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:#ffb280;
}
.snippet h2 {
    font: 16px Arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:left;
    margin: 5px 0 15px;
}
.affiches, .sorties {
    width:250px;
}
.affiche, .sortie {
    width:93px;
    height:122px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0 22px 22px 0;
}
.sortie {
    height:62px;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
@-ms-viewport{width:208px}
@viewport{width:208px}
```

HTML:

```
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
<div class="snippet">
<h2>sorties de la semaine</h2>

<div class="affiches">
<a href="page2.html" class="bouton affiche" data-zone="cine" data-method="top/bbar"></a>
<a href="page2.html" class="bouton affiche" data-zone="cine" data-method="top/bbar"></a>
<a href="page2.html" class="bouton affiche" data-zone="cine" data-method="top/bbar"></a>
<a href="page2.html" class="bouton affiche" data-zone="cine" data-method="top/bbar"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is happen with windows Phone on this side? Why don't you use the body directly instead of `.snippet`? + Please always provide the code here as well.

Answer (score 0):

Hope these links helps:

- [Windows Phone 8 and Device-Width](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/).
- [Managing the Windows Phone Browser Viewport](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2011/03/14/managing-the-windows-phone-browser-viewport.aspx).